# How do you handle Country Code TLD names in your packages/namespaces?

Tags: naming-conventions, namespaces, package

The convention is that you use your company's domain. That is quite simple but what if it is something like www.mycompany.co.uk.

Now this wouldn't be a problem if it were www.mycompany.com. That is fairly simple com.mycompany.Class

What are we meant to do with the first?

uk.co.mycompany.Class OR co.uk.mycompany.Class? Or something else altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

uk.co.mycompany.Class

It is a simple reverse of your URL. Note that in the first example the domain you actually own is mycompany.com, not just www.mycompany.com

Comment: sorry yes. Little slip. The other irritating thing is that it adds ANOTHER folder to browse through if you are using Java. Maybe placing them together, couk.mycompany?

Comment: In reality, unless you are releasing the product as something that has the possibility of namespace collision (SDK, developer library, Android) there is little true need to stick to the standard.

Comment: @quiDium: "adds ANOTHER folder to browse through" Just use a decent IDE, which will present packages as a reasonable structure :-). Eclipse e.g. does this (Package view).

Answer (score 0):

If that is how your supposed to write your namespaces, I'd say that `uk.co.mycompany.Class` fits best with your first example.

It also seems to me that this is pretty subjective, and you should define a standard, and stick with it.

Comment: FYI Java's official recommendations are to use the inverse of the company's URL for namespaces. A bit odd but it means fewer collisions in the wild.